Ordinal vs one-hot encoding when all features are categorical
Dealing with categorical data is not as straightforward as dealing with continuous data, since all ML algorithms expect their input in a numeric format. As such, when our features are categorical in nature, a preprocessing step is necessary to convert them into numbers.
The consensus is that categorical features without any order (aka nominal) should be one-hot encoded, while features that follow an order should be ordinal (integer) encoded. However, I am not sure if this distinction is relevant when all features are categorical.
Example
Given a sample with two nominal features $(x_1, x_2)$ each taking 3 values, we are asked to predict its class (for simplicity binary, 0 or 1). Suppose we ordinal (integer) encode them. All we need is to find a model that maps $\{0, 1, 2\} \times \{0, 1, 2\}$, that is the 9 possible combinations of $(x_1, x_2)$, into 0 or 1.
From a purely mathematical perspective, any algorithm capable of returning a model that correctly classifies each of the 9 points in the input space would suffice. I think things gets more nuanced when we take into consideration how a given algorithm "learns".
For example, suppose we select kNN as the learning algorithm, set $k=5$ and there are 2 training samples for each combination of $(x_1, x_2)$. A new query point $x' = (0, 0)$ needs to be predicted. Given that we have only two training samples with values $(0, 0)$, inevitably the values for $(0/1, 1/0)$ must also checked. Since the ordering was arbitrary, it is not guaranteed that we will get good results. Of course, with more data (specifically with more than 5 training samples per combination), the effect of arbitrary order/distance should disappear.
Since the input space would be filled up only with these 9 combinations, that is we won't observe an input like $(0.5, 1.5)$, does it really matter if we one-hot or integer encode? Does the choice depend solely on the nature of the machine learning algorithm?

The point of one-hor-encoding is that it converts the problem to one in a vector space, for which many ML algorithms exist (or can be easily adapted.) In your knn example one has to define the metric measuring distance between the categorical features - whether they are encoded or not shouldn't change the result. The issue that seems problematic likely stems from the specific implementation of the algorithm that you have in mind.
